# How do I get Excel data to paste properly into Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, type-conversion

I have an SQL back-end. The data type(s) I've tried are `VarChar(255)` and `NVarChar`. Neither of which seem to work.

The problem is when I paste into the Columns into Access every part number that has a `-` in it does not paste and the records are blank. All of the other part numbers populate just fine.

Example

```
Part Number 100005 = pastes fine
Part Number 10005-5 = does not paste at all
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a setting I need to toggle somewhere? I thought `VarChar(255)` would do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried using "paste special"?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a ' character before the part  values, to tell Excel to treat that value as Text - i.e. double click to enter the cell, put a ' before the value, then hit enter. Then copy and paste the value into Access.

Comment: That did not work. I maybe a little lost but not sure how that would help me achieve what I'm trying to do anyway.